# lodash - isEqual ignore undefined

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I use lodash to deep check the equality of two objects, ignoring undefined.

i.e.

```
const a = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const b = { a: 1 };

_.isEqual(a, b); // => true
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it return false tho

Comment: @ucup yes my question is, is it possible to get that output

Comment: @Balastrong a recursive for-loop which works but I was wondering if there was a 1-liner in lodash

Comment: what do you mean? you want it to return true ?

Comment: @ucup yes i doa

Comment: @Spectric my question is to ignore undefined/non present keys from equality checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_.isMatch()` which performs a partial deep comparison between object (`a`) and source (`b`) to determine if object **contains** equivalent property values to source.

```js
const a = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const b = { a: 1 };

console.log(_.isEqual(a, b)); // false
console.log(_.isMatch(a, b)); // true
console.log(_.isMatch(b, a)); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

This would only work if a key doesn't exist on the source. If a key exist with an explicit value of `undefined`, the result would be false.

```js
const a = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const b = { a: 1, c: undefined };

console.log(_.isMatch(a, b)); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```